# what exactly maven dependency tag does?

Tags: eclipse, maven-3

I have started reading and trying maven since yesterday. But its making me go crazy.
I am java developer but never came across ant or maven before.

I want to know what exactly happens with the dependency tag in POM.xml file?
Lets say, I am using camel framework and want to use camel core jars.
If one of my class file contains following line:

```
CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
```

so what exactly I need to do after that?
Do I need to include the jars myself in the class path or dependency tag will download the jar files over internet for me?

If the case is former, what dependency tag will do? & where should I place my jar files? I mean is there any specific location on my hard drive? and 
if the case is lateral then during compile time I get error "cannot be resolved to a type"

And the imports are to be specified or not?

I know the question might sound silly but I am not able to find its answer.
I have tried googling alot, it didn't help me still.

Any help would be greatful, even help on maven topics which I might come across in near future would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Solved. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/20094312/1121208 for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got what I needed to know
Sharing it for others who may stuck up in same situation

*Does dependency tag download the jar specified?*

maven dependency tag actually downloads the jar files you specify in the dependency tag. It downloads and save it under .m2/repositories(local repository) folder on your hard drive (along with some information like last updated, etc)

Local repository is shared among all your projects

*from where it downloads?*

It downloads the jar from the central repositories. There central repositories contain almost all the open source jar files one needs in a project. It downloads based on information you provide in groupid, artifactid, etc.

http://repo1.maven.org/maven/

http://mvnrepository.com/

can be checked for correct groupid, etc

Once these jar files are downloaded, they are automatically added to the classpath and are available in your project for use.

If the jar files you are searching for, are not available in the central repository, maven may throw error, in that case you can download it manually and let maven know about it.

Answer (score 0):

dependency tag will download the jar specified in the dependency tag for you if available. Otherwise will raise a pom.xml error - could not found dependency..

Imports have nothing to do with maven. They will appear when you will you another class in your class/java file. So if you import in build path the jar by yourserf or if you put it there with maven, you will have the import.

Are you using eclipse or any other ide ?

Comment: Yeah I am using eclipse

Comment: What I need is the core basic stuff.. can u help with the comment in another answer?

Answer (score 0):

Without maven you need to put jars into lib folder.

With maven you specify as declaration inside `<dependencies>`

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

and when you do `mvn package`, maven will download required jars on your PC.

With Eclipse and m2e (maven eclipse integration) you can do that all not leaving Eclipse,
and even get sources for used libraries automatically.

Read http://maven.apache.org/ It worth it.

Comment: dependency tag I got, but my question is how will it know from where to download? I mean from which url?

Comment: and secondly while I am writing code, during that time its giving error "cannot be resolved to a type". If I download the jar files and add that to libraries using "add external jars", that error will go.. but when using maven I guess I don't need to download the jars and etc (if I am not wrong), so how will that compile time error go??? Please don't mind if the question is too basic.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Maven is a build tool. It doesn't run your app. It builds it. So, at runtime, the classpath needs to be set like for any oter application yo would have built with something else.

When you build an app, you depend on external libraries. The dependencies mechanism of Maven simply lets you declare wwhich libraries your ap needs. When you build your app, Maven downloads these libraries from a central repository (or sevaral ones), and stores them in a local repository on your hard drive. These jars are automatically added to the build classpath by Maven. At runtime though, depending on the kind of ap you're building, you'll have to copy or embed those jars in order to create a runnable application.

The rules of Java don't change just you build them with Maven. Meven uses the stadard Java compiler (`javac`). And of course, if you want to use a class by its simple name, you'll have to add an `import` statement for this class.

I think that, before using Maven, you should try to compile and run a simple application depending on an external library without using any IDE. You would then understand better all the steps that are required to build and run an app, the concept of build and runtime classpath, etc.

Comment: If working without IDE would help, I will do that as the first thing. Lets try.